# How to set timer on body onload?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to set timer on body `onload eventHandler` to call function where I show hide div.

```
<body onload="">
    <div style="display:none;"> hide </div>
</body>
```

Comment: please explain a bit more.

Comment: @Konza - The time which i set on onload function that time interval I want to display my div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For better readability, I've put the code in a separate function.
- I've added an id to the `div` for easier selection through javascript.
- In the `onload` attribute, I'm calling `setInterval`, which gets an anonymous function as a first parameter.
- This function will be called every time after the interval (1000 ms) elapses.
- The function will then select the element with the id `theDiv`, and set its css `display` attribute to `block`, or `none` (depending on the previous value).

JSFiddle for demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/GAE8L/1/

Note that the first parameter for `setInterval` is just the function name, not a function call (so no parenthesis!):

```
<body onload="setInterval(onTimerElapsed, 1000);">
    <div id="theDiv" style="display:none;">
        hide
    </div>
</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function onTimerElapsed() {
        var myDiv = document.getElementById('theDiv');
        myDiv.style.display = myDiv.style.display === 'none' ? 'block' : 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Comment: again I want to hide on that time interval. It should be a continuous process of hide show.

Comment: Is there any way to do?

Comment: Yes, sorry I misunderstood what you wanted. I've updated the JSFiddle, and the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<div id="div1" style="display:none;">
hide
</div>

<script>
$(function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
            $('#div1').show();
    }, 1000);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use jquery, it less..

```
  function foo() {
    // method show should be called.
    $("#idDiv").show();
  }

  function bar() {
    setTimeout(foo(), 1000)
  }

</script>
</code>
 <body onload="bar()">

 </body>
```

Comment: This will not work, you are calling foo in the `setTimeout()` line, instead of passing a reference to the function.

Comment: @UweB - Yeah its not working. Please suggest me how to write function? I want to hide show div in give time interval.