# Enable href using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a JavaScript function using which I am disabling a hyperlink and it does the trick. Now after a few seconds lets say after 4 secs I want to enable the link. I am not sure how to do this. I've written a function to enable the link but it is not working.

Can someone please help using JavaScript.

JS functions

```
function disableDownloadReportLink(link) {
     link.onclick = function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
     }
   }   

 function enableDownloadReportLink() {
     document.getElementById('downloadReportLink').href.disabled = false;
   }
```

Comment: it might be easier to hide/show the element that has the `href` attribute

Comment: How is disableDownloadReportLink called?

Comment: Simply set a timer, see here for an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721159/how-to-set-timer-on-body-onload

Comment: This is how I am calling it. <a href="#x" id="downloadReportLink" title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions." onclick="document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit(),disableDownloadReportLink(this),enableDownloadReportLink()"><span>Export E-Sign Information</span></a>

Comment: There's no such thing as `element.href.disabled`, that property doesn't exist ?

Comment: @adeneo - it does exist (if you make it)... it just doesn't do anything...

Answer (score 2):

Basically, the same pattern as @Vicente Olivert Riera , just a different implementation, using `add/remove EventListener` ...

```
<a href="./foo" id="my-link">foo</a>

<script>
function disableLink(link) {
    var handler = function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log('click disabled');
    }
    link.addEventListener('click', handler, false);
    link.dataset.disableHandler = handler;
}
function enableLink(link) {
    if (link.dataset.disableHandler) {
        link.removeEventListener('click', link.dataset.disableHandler);
        link.dataset.disableHandler = null;
    }
}

var link = document.getElementById('my-link');
disableLink(link);
link.style.color = 'grey';
console.log('link disabled');

setTimeout(function(){
    enableLink(link);
    link.style.color = 'blue';
    console.log('link enabled');
}, 4000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a a timer in the on load funktion. This has been asked before, see here for an example [How to set timer on body onload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721159/how-to-set-timer-on-body-onload)

Answer (score 0):

Add a class .inactive on which you would bind a click event to e.preventDefault();

After 4 sec, remove the class.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function disableDownloadReportLink(link) {
  link.onclick = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
}

function enableDownloadReportLink(link) {
  link.onclick = undefined;
}

var el = document.getElementById("wop");

disableDownloadReportLink(el);

setTimeout(
  function() {
    enableDownloadReportLink(el); 
  },
  4000
);
```

```html
<a id="wop" href="http://www.google.com">I will work after 4 seconds!</a>
```

Basically what you have done with `disableDownloadReportLink` is to disable what the `onclick` event does. What you can do if you want the link to work normally again is to set `onclick` to `undefined`:

```
function enableDownloadReportLink(link) {
    link.onclick = undefined;
}
```

You can put the call to `enableDownloadReportLink` into a `setTimeout` in order to do it after 4 seconds:

```
setTimeout(
  function() {
    enableDownloadReportLink(link);                                                                                                                              
  },
  4000
);
```

---

For your question about how to call those functions, this is what I would do, as I told you in my comment (don't expect this snippet to work, is only an example):

```js
function doEverything(link) {
  // submit integration report
  document.getElementById('viewIntegrationReport').submit();

  // disable link
  disableDownloadReportLink(link);

  // enable link after 4 seconds
  setTimeout(
    function() {
      enableDownloadReportLink(link);
    },  
    4000
  );  
}
```

```html
<a href="#x" id="downloadReportLink" title="This function will provide you a 30 day download of all your eSign transactions." onclick="doEverything(this);"><span>Export E-Sign Information</span></a>
```

Comment: How would you call these functions then?

Comment: I think you already have everything you need. How you call those functions is up to you. Why don't you call a function (when you click the link) which does everything, instead of in-lining the call to three functions in the link's onclick? That new function will do the `submit()`, then will call the function to disable the link, and then (after 4 seconds, using the `setTimeout`) will call the function to enable the link.

Comment: As I said in my answer, "don't expect this snippet to work, is only an example". You have to adapt it to your code.