# How to create a timer which starts automatically as soon as a specific webpage is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, timer, tampermonkey, stopwatch

I want to create a timer which starts automatically as soon as the webpage is loaded and tracks the time I spend on the page before I click on "submit" on that webpage. Is this possible using a tamper monkey script?

I want to track time spent on filling form links.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to set timer on body onload?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21721159/how-to-set-timer-on-body-onload)

Comment: Hi @Hyderabadi and welcome to Stack Overflow. You might have to modify your question a little bit before you can expect users of this site to attempt an answer. I encourage you to take a look at the guidelines for asking questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking. Don't be afraid to ask for guidance in the comments.

Comment: Yes, it is possible with a userscript, just find the code that best suits you and add it on a Tampermonkey script

Answer (score 1):

Set a timer on page load.
Than, when submit is clicked just stop the timer.

```html
<script>
window.onload = function() {
  var incrementSecond = function () {
    window.secondsPassed += 1;
    console.log('+1 sec, now we have', window.secondsPassed);
  }

  window.secondsPassed = 0;
  window.myTimer = setInterval(incrementSecond, 1000);
}
var onSubmitClick = function() {
  window.clearInterval(window.myTimer); // always clean resources
  // call some other function to do the submit
}
</script>

<input type="submit" onClick="onSubmitClick"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply set a new date variable when the page loads and set another when the user clicks submit and find the difference.

```
<script>
var start;

window.onload = function(){
    start = new Date();
}

function myFunction() {
    var end = new Date();
    var diff = Math.abs(end - start);
    alert(diff);
}
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help Cody.It is showing me an alert with Four digit number.May i know how can i get a time instead in seconds or minutes.

Comment: @Hyderabadi check my post. it might be useful. But if you want use date as source, you can use format fo that class, go check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14638018/current-time-formatting-with-javascript

Comment: @Hyderabadi, that is the elapsed time in milliseconds. To get seconds, divide the result by 1000.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this codepen 
https://codepen.io/shivani137/pen/aYjaKG

`setInterval(function() {}, 1000)` can help you achive this feature

Comment: Thank you for such quick reply and guidance.

Comment: But i have a question how do i use the above code in tamper monkey to run automatically when the web page is loaded and can we display a digital timer instead.   Thank you.